# Utf8 in symfony2 is not working

Tags: symfony, utf-8, phpmyadmin, doctrine

I'm trying to copy my localhost copy of a symfony2 website to a new shared server. I'm exporting the database with phpMyAdmin and charset in utf8, and importing too with phpMyAdmin and charset in utf8. After import successfully I can see the data with the expected accent with phpMyAdmin, so, all seem to be good, but when I render the web pages I see a lot of � characters and only in the data obtained from database. In config.yml doctrine/dbal/charset is set to UTF8, and also already have a `<meta charset="utf-8">`. What other configuration could be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: collation of your database ?

Comment: Now that you ask for, I don't know , because I created it from cpanel without options. :-| . I'm going to check

Comment: I manually changed to utf8 but still the same result

Comment: What was the collation in the old database? When you changed the collation in the new database, you have to reinsert the data or change the data itself (which phpMyAdmin can do for you) to match the new collation (because changing the collation doesn't adjust the existing data).